# Comparing Prefabs in a Memory Card Game

Tags: unity, c#

I need to compare two cards together to check if the two cards is identical. Currently I have a prefabs folder with 18 images which are duplicated in the same folder, so the total cards is 36. How can I make unity identify that 2 cards are the same. Till now I can only click on the Back Prefab and see the card behind it.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an id for each type of card so you can compare them? Trying to compare if it comes from the same prefab seems like a pretty fishy idea

Comment: Currently i have the 18 cards duplicated in the same folder for example i have Messi and Messi1 which are the same prefab. Do you have any code on how can i compare them?

Comment: What do Messi and Messi1 have in common that is different in the other prefabs?

Comment: They are the same image but with different names because obviously you can't name them the same

Comment: Then just compare if the names are the same...

Comment: Can i compare them with a tag? And what code do i need?

Comment: You need to know that if you want to get any better at some point, you have to try by yourself, as we are not going to code your game for you

Comment: But i'm stuck in this part and i don't have the chance to try

Comment: I just told you to compare the names. I do not know if it is the best solution, but if you cannot even try that, I cannot do anything for you

Comment: Might as well not commented in the first place if you don't want to help

Comment: @Paul : If you don't show any effort about resolving your problem, nobody will feel like helping you. I don't think that checking if two strings are equals is a big deal... You haven't provided any code, what you have tried....

Answer (score 0):

Just add a script to all of the cards called `Card`, make an ID variable in the script, give a unique ID to each card and compare them to each other.